# Cordova deeplinks issue with Ionic Tabbar

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using the plugin Cordova Deeplinks (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-deeplinks) to go back to my app after an oauth authentification.
Everything seems correct, but when the Dashboard is displayed (with tab bar), there are some issues with the tab bar.
Custom icons are not displayed (everything is white), and there is "a lag": when I click on the second tab, icons are displayed but this is the first one which is active; when I click on the third tab, it's the second icon which is active etc.

I tried to debug it with the chrome inspect, icon's class has "active" parameter or not. The problem is that this is not the right icon which has the parameter "active".
I tried to put the tab template into the .ts file, but this is the same.
I tried to put .setRoot(Page) instead of .push(Page), but it doesn't work.
I tried to put in the constructor of the first page of the tab             this.navCtrl.parent.select(0); icons are not hidden but there is the lag.

Can anyone had this problem and can help me ?

Comment: Add something that you tried

Comment: I added what I tried